# MYSQL Count Distinct year make model in single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey folks I'll do my best to explain this.  I have a table of vehicles, lets say there is ID, year, make, model.

```
|----------------------------|
|ID  | year | make  | model  |
|----------------------------|
|1   | 2004 | Chevy | Silve..|
|2   | 2004 | Ford  | F-150  |
|3   | 2003 | Chevy | Silve..|
|4   | 2002 | Chevy | Silve..|
|5   | 2002 | Chevy | Silve..|
|6   | 2002 | Chevy | Silve..|
|----------------------------|
```

I want to query the table and return distinct 'year' and a count of how many vehicles there are for that year.

```
 2004 (2)
 2003 (1)
 2002 (3)
```

Alternatively I would like to select distinct make and return how many vehicles are also that make.

```
 Chevy (5)
 Ford (1)
```

At the end of the day I'd like to be able to put that all together to get something like this

```
 2004 Chevy Silve.. (1)
 2004 Ford F-150 (1)
 2003 Chevy Silve.. (1)
 2002 Chevy Silve.. (3)
```

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Is there any way to do this in cakephp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First query:

```
SELECT `year`, COUNT(DISTINCT `make`) N
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY `year`
```

Second query:

```
SELECT `make`, COUNT(*) N
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY `make`
```

Third query:

```
SELECT `year`, `make`, `model`, COUNT(*) N
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY `year`, `make`, `model`
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick response.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in cakephp?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a single query itself. You need count of Vehicles broken down in to make and year. The below query will work for that

```
SELECT MAKE, YEAR, COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY YEAR, MAKE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select year, make, model, count(*) as count
from vehicles
group by year, make, model
order by year, make, model
```